# unwanted vertical and inter-word space - tabularx

Tags: spacing, tabularx, line-spacing

I am trying to create a calendar with `tabularx` package. I managed to get the tables right but there seems to be a lot of space between the words and between the lines. It reminds me of MS Word document in justified alignment, wherein unnecessary spaces between words appear out of nowhere.

**Question:**

1. How can I reduce the line spacing and get rid of the spaces between words? [*That will give me some space to include two more rows for two more weeks.*]
2. Is there anything that I am doing wrong? [*Of course, I am not sure if this the right method to create a calendar.*]

I have quite some text to include within each "box", as it can be seen from the MWE and the screen shot of the PDF output. [*I don't know why a line appears on top of "JANUARY".*]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[xetex,a4paper,landscape,margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[final]{microtype}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}

\newcolumntype{C}{>{ \Large \arraybackslash}X}
\newcommand{\ti}{\fontsize{14}{11}\selectfont }
\newcommand{\wday}{\bfseries \fontsize{15}{11}\selectfont}
\newcommand{\dat}{\bfseries \fontsize{15}{11}\selectfont}


\begin{document}
\begin{center}
            \Huge \textbf{JANUARY}
    \end{center}
\begin{tabularx}{28cm}{@{\rule[-2ex]{0pt}{5ex}}|*{7}{C|}}
    \hline
    {\wday MON} & {\wday TUE} & {\wday WED} & {\wday THU} & {\wday FRI} & {\wday SAT} & {\wday SUN}   \\ \hline 
    {\dat 2} \textbf{Putradā Ekādaśī}   & 
    {\dat 3} {\ti [06:59 - 10:44]; \textbf{App.}  Śrī Jagadīśa  Paṇḍita} & 
    {\dat 4} {\ti } & 
    {\dat 5} {\ti } & 
    {\dat 6} {\ti Śrī Kṛṣṇa Puṣya Abhiśeka}     &
    {\dat 7} {\ti \textbf{Māga māsa begins}}& 
    {\dat 8} {\ti }  \\ 
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\  &  &  &  &  &  & \\ \hline
    {\dat 9} {\ti }& 
    {\dat 10} {\ti } & 
    {\dat 11} {\ti } & 
    {\dat 12}   {\ti [footnote]\footnote{\textbf{Disapp.:} Śrī Rāmacandra Kavirāja; \textbf{App.:} Śrīla Gopāla Bhaṭṭa Gosvāmī}} & 
    {\dat 13} {\ti \textbf{Disapp.:} Śrī Jayadeva Gosvāmī}  &  
    {\dat 14} {\ti \textbf{Disapp.:} Śrī Locana Dāsa Ṭhākūra, Makara Śaṅkrāntī} & 
    {\dat 15} {\ti }\\ 
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\  &  &  &  &  &  & \\ \hline
    {\dat 16}  & 
    {\dat 17}  & 
    {\dat 18} \textbf{Ṣaṭ-tila Ekādaśī} & 
    {\dat 19} {\ti [07:03 - 10:49]} & 
    {\dat 20} & 
    {\dat 21} & 
    {\dat 22} \\ 
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\  &  &  &  &  &  & \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image: OUTPUT]

Comment: you are justfying use `\newcolumntype{C}{>{ \Large}\raggedright \arraybackslash}X}`

Comment: `\fontsize{15}{11}\selectfont}` ????  15pt font on lines 11pt apart?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Is {15}{11} a cause of weird spaces? What should be the parameter? Can you please explain?

Comment: raggedright as in first comment will fix the spacing, your fontsize calls are just weird, why not use \large ? it is almost always wrong for the second argument to be less than the first but better to use one of the named sizes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @DavidCarlisle has already noted in a couple of comments, you need to added `\raggedright` in the column definition. Proper usage of `\fontsize` requires the second argument to at least as large as, and generally about 20% larger than, the first argument.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[a4paper,landscape,margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}

\newcolumntype{L}{>{\Large\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcommand{\ti}{\fontsize{14}{17}\selectfont }
\newcommand{\wday}{\bfseries \fontsize{15}{18}\selectfont}
\newcommand{\dat}{\bfseries  \fontsize{15}{18}\selectfont}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\Huge \textbf{JANUARY}
\end{center}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{\rule[-2ex]{0pt}{5ex}} |*{7}{L|}}
    \hline
    \wday MON & \wday TUE & \wday WED & \wday THU & 
    \wday FRI & \wday SAT & \wday SUN   \\ \hline 
    {\dat  2} \textbf{Putradā Ekādaśī}   & 
    {\dat  3} \ti [06:59--10:44]; \textbf{App.}  Śrī Jagadīśa  Paṇḍita & 
    {\dat  4} {\ti } & 
    {\dat  5} {\ti } & 
    {\dat  6} \ti Śrī Kṛṣṇa Puṣya Abhiśeka     &
    {\dat  7} \ti \textbf{Māga māsa begins}& 
    {\dat  8} {\ti } \\ 
    &  &  &  &  &  & \\  
    &  &  &  &  &  & \\ \hline
    {\dat  9} {\ti } & 
    {\dat 10} {\ti } & 
    {\dat 11} {\ti } & 
    {\dat 12} {\ti [footnote]\footnote{%
    \textbf{Disapp.:} Śrī Rāmacandra Kavirāja; 
    \textbf{App.:} Śrīla Gopāla Bhaṭṭa Gosvāmī}} & 
    {\dat 13} \ti \textbf{Disapp.:} Śrī Jayadeva Gosvāmī  &  
    {\dat 14} \ti \textbf{Disapp.:} Śrī Locana Dāsa Ṭhākūra, Makara Śaṅkrāntī & 
    {\dat 15} {\ti } \\ 
    &  &  &  &  &  & \\  
    &  &  &  &  &  & \\ \hline
    {\dat 16} & 
    {\dat 17} & 
    {\dat 18} \textbf{Ṣaṭ-tila Ekādaśī} & 
    {\dat 19} \ti [07:03--10:49] & 
    {\dat 20} & 
    {\dat 21} & 
    {\dat 22} \\ 
    &  &  &  &  &  & \\  
    &  &  &  &  &  & \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\usepackage[latvian]{babel} % is this correct?` No. This is IAST [International Alphabet for Sanskrit Transliteration]. Generally, I don't use `babel`. `polylossia` does the job nicely.

Comment: @VrajarajaGovindaDas - Thanks for providing this correction; I've reverted the code to loading `polyglossia` instead of `babel`. Note that since your code doesn't define a main or default language, loading `polyglossia` amounts to just loading the `fontspec` package.

Comment: Yeah. There's wasn't a need to define a main or default language since the alphabets are Roman, isn't it?

Comment: Thanks. Your code works. I see that you have changed `C` to `L` in this line. `\newcolumntype{L}{>{\Large\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}`, Does that indicate `left aligned` and `center aligned` respectively?

Comment: @VrajarajaGovindaDas - Indeed, I changed `C` to `L` for the reason you suggested: `C` might be mistaken for some to mean "centered". Naturally, you're entirely free to adopt whatever naming convention you feel comfortable with.

Comment: @VrajarajaGovindaDas - About setting a (main) language with either babel or polyglossia: My point was that if you don't intend to set a language, there's no reason for loading `polyglossia` or `babel` in the first place. Loading the `fontspec` package directly would be all that's required. (Aside: the `polyglossia` package loads `fontspec` automatically.)

Comment: I generally load `polyglossia` by default since most of my documents are bilingual or trilingual. Anyway `fontspec` also gets loaded as explained by you for mono-lingual documents. And, my primary compiler is XeLaTeX.

Comment: Reg. `C` and `L` : Does it mean it is just a variable? Any alphabet will do the job [either CAPS or small letters]?

Comment: @VrajarajaGovindaDas - The LaTeX kernel sets up the `l`, `c`, `r`, and `p` column types. (The `p` stands for `paragraph`.) These are not just "variable names" that can be assigned to any column type. Various packages define additional column types. E.g., the `tabularx` and `dcolumn` packages define the `X` and `D` column types, respectively. Given that the letters `l`, `c`, and `r` are taken, I think it's good practice to use "free" or previously unassigned lowercase and uppercase letters carefully and in (mild) conformance with the existing naming patterns.

Comment: Thank you!! That was a good explanation.